# On make make install, building application getting ISO c does not permit named variadic

Tags: c++, c, ubuntu, makefile

/.configure, make and make install

This is code for status.h

```
#define DEBUG(level, args...) debug(level, __location__, __FUNCTION__, args)


typedef enum {
        ST_OK = 0,
        ST_GENERAL_FAILURE = 1,
        ST_NO_SUCH_OBJECT = 2,
        ST_READ_ERROR = 3,
        ST_WRITE_ERROR = 4,
        ST_PARSE_ERROR = 5,
        ST_LOG_ERR = 117,
        ST_DATABASE_FAILURE = 118,
        ST_BIND_FAILURE = 119,
        ST_SOCKET_FAILURE = 120,
        ST_CONFIGURATION_ERROR = 121,
        ST_ASSERTION_FAILED = 122,
        ST_NOT_IMPLEMENTED = 123,
        ST_OUT_OF_MEMORY = 124,
} STATUS;

#define NO_MEM_RETURN(ptr) {if (ptr == NULL) { DEBUG(0, "Out of memory"); return ST_OUT_OF_MEMORY; }}
#define NO_MEM_RETURN_RV(ptr, rv) {if (ptr == NULL) { DEBUG(0, "Out of memory"); return rv; }}


STATUS debug(int loglevel, const char *location, const char *function, ...);
```

This is code for code for chirond.c and currently running on gcc version 4.7.2 (Debian 4.7.2-5)

```
    #include "includes.h"
    #include "build/ndr_chiron.h"
    #include "build/chiron.h"
    #include <nettle/md5.h>
    #include <nettle/arcfour.h>

    #define CHIRON_PORT "53165"

    struct chiron_context {
            int clientfd;
            struct sockaddr *clientaddr;
            char *account_code;
            char *device_id;
            uint8_t md5_last_out[0x10];
            uint8_t rc4key[0x10];
    };

    /* FIXME This function is a nasty little hack. */
    char *ndr_print_chiron_msg_type_enum(TALLOC_CTX *mem_ctx, enum chiron_msg_type msg_type) {
            char *ret;
            struct ndr_print *ndr_print = talloc_zero(mem_ctx, struct ndr_print);
            ndr_print->print = ndr_print_string_helper;
            ndr_print->depth = 0;
            ndr_print_chiron_msg_type(ndr_print, "", msg_type);
            ret = talloc_steal(mem_ctx, ndr_print->private_data);
            talloc_free(ndr_print);
            return ret;
    }
STATUS handle_chiron_msg_response(struct chiron_context *ctx, struct chiron_message *msg) {
#if 0 // TLV, move to ASN.1 parsing
        DATA_BLOB crypted, decrypted;
        enum ndr_err_code ndr_err;
        struct chiron_msg_inner_response *inner_response;
        struct arcfour_ctx rc4;
        char *deviceid_string;

        if (memcmp(msg->msg.response.md5_check, ctx->md5_last_out, 0x10)) {
                DEBUG(0, "MD5 does not match!\n");
                return ST_PARSE_ERROR;
        }
        DEBUG(0, "Handling the response");
        inner_response = talloc(msg, struct chiron_msg_inner_response);
        NO_MEM_RETURN(inner_response);

        /* Copy packet to crypted data blob */
        crypted.length = msg->msg.response.length - MD5_HASH_LEN;
        crypted.data = talloc_memdup(msg, msg->msg.response.payload, crypted.length);
        NO_MEM_RETURN(crypted.data);

        decrypted.data = talloc_array(msg, uint8_t, crypted.length);
        NO_MEM_RETURN(decrypted.data);
        decrypted.length = crypted.length;

        arcfour_set_key(&rc4, MD5_HASH_LEN, ctx->rc4key);
        arcfour_crypt(&rc4, crypted.length, decrypted.data, crypted.data);

        /* Parse the packet */
        ndr_err = ndr_pull_struct_blob_all(&decrypted, inner_response, inner_response, (ndr_pull_flags_fn_t)ndr_pull_chiron_msg_inner_response);

        if (ndr_err != NDR_ERR_SUCCESS) {
                DEBUG(0, "Could not parse the inner response");
                return ST_PARSE_ERROR;
        }
STATUS handle_chiron_msg_response(struct chiron_context *ctx, struct chiron_message *msg) {
#if 0 // TLV, move to ASN.1 parsing
        DATA_BLOB crypted, decrypted;
        enum ndr_err_code ndr_err;
        struct chiron_msg_inner_response *inner_response;
        struct arcfour_ctx rc4;
        char *deviceid_string;

        if (memcmp(msg->msg.response.md5_check, ctx->md5_last_out, 0x10)) {
                DEBUG(0, "MD5 does not match!\n");
                return ST_PARSE_ERROR;
        }
        DEBUG(0, "Handling the response");
        inner_response = talloc(msg, struct chiron_msg_inner_response);
        NO_MEM_RETURN(inner_response);

        /* Copy packet to crypted data blob */
        crypted.length = msg->msg.response.length - MD5_HASH_LEN;
        crypted.data = talloc_memdup(msg, msg->msg.response.payload, crypted.length);
        NO_MEM_RETURN(crypted.data);

        decrypted.data = talloc_array(msg, uint8_t, crypted.length);
        NO_MEM_RETURN(decrypted.data);
        decrypted.length = crypted.length;

        arcfour_set_key(&rc4, MD5_HASH_LEN, ctx->rc4key);
        arcfour_crypt(&rc4, crypted.length, decrypted.data, crypted.data);

        /* Parse the packet */
        ndr_err = ndr_pull_struct_blob_all(&decrypted, inner_response, inner_response, (ndr_pull_flags_fn_t)ndr_pull_chiron_msg_inner_response);

        if (ndr_err != NDR_ERR_SUCCESS) {
                DEBUG(0, "Could not parse the inner response");
                return ST_PARSE_ERROR;
        }
DEBUG(0, "%s", ndr_print_struct_string(msg,(ndr_print_fn_t)ndr_print_chiron_msg_inner_response, "chiron payload", inner_response));

        deviceid_string = talloc_zero_array(msg, char, inner_response->dev_len + 1);
        memcpy(deviceid_string, inner_response->deviceid, inner_response->dev_len);

        DEBUG(0, "Remote device: %s", deviceid_string);
#endif
        //send_chiron_msg_key
        return ST_OK;
}


STATUS send_chiron_msg_challenge(struct chiron_context *ctx, struct chiron_message *in) {
        struct chiron_message *out = talloc_zero(in, struct chiron_message);
        struct md5_ctx md5;
        uint8_t *md5input;
        enum ndr_err_code ndr_err;
        DATA_BLOB raw_out;

        NO_MEM_RETURN(out);
        DEBUG(0, "Sending out a challenge");

        out->msg_type = CHIRON_CHALLENGE;
        out->seq = in->seq;
        out->flags = in->flags;

        /* Make an md5 hash of the account code with the seq byte appended. */
        md5input = talloc_array(in, uint8_t, in->msg.account.length + 1);
        NO_MEM_RETURN(md5input);

        memcpy(md5input, in->msg.account.account_code, in->msg.account.length);
        md5input[in->msg.account.length] = in->seq;

        out->msg.challenge.md5_check = talloc_array(out, uint8_t, MD5_HASH_LEN);
        NO_MEM_RETURN(out->msg.challenge.md5_check);

        md5_init(&md5);
        md5_update(&md5, in->msg.account.length + 1, md5input);
        md5_digest(&md5, MD5_HASH_LEN, out->msg.challenge.md5_check);
        talloc_free(md5input);

        /* FIXME This should be random, but that is annoying for testing purposes */
        out->msg.challenge.length = MD5_HASH_LEN + CHALLENGE_LEN;
        out->msg.challenge.challenge = talloc_zero_array(out, uint8_t, CHALLENGE_LEN);
        NO_MEM_RETURN(out->msg.challenge.challenge);
        out->msg.challenge.challenge[0] = 0xd0;
        out->msg.challenge.challenge[1] = 0x8b;
        out->msg.challenge.challenge[2] = 0x29;
        out->msg.challenge.challenge[3] = 0xd3;
        out->msg.challenge.challenge[4] = 0x7c;
        out->msg.challenge.challenge[5] = 0xfd;
        out->msg.challenge.challenge[6] = 0xb5;
        out->msg.challenge.challenge[7] = 0xc6;
        out->msg.challenge.challenge[8] = 0x1e;

        ndr_err = ndr_push_struct_blob(&raw_out, out, out, (ndr_push_flags_fn_t)ndr_push_chiron_message);
        if (ndr_err != NDR_ERR_SUCCESS) {
                DEBUG(0, "Error writing NDR data blob.");
                return ST_WRITE_ERROR;
        }
 /* Update the md5 check for the next message (last 9 bytes with the seq byte appended). */
        md5input = talloc_array(in, uint8_t, CHALLENGE_LEN + 1);
        NO_MEM_RETURN(md5input);

        memcpy(md5input, &raw_out.data[MSG_HDR_LEN + MD5_HASH_LEN], CHALLENGE_LEN);
        md5input[CHALLENGE_LEN] = in->seq;

        md5_init(&md5);
        md5_update(&md5, CHALLENGE_LEN + 1, md5input);
        md5_digest(&md5, MD5_HASH_LEN, ctx->md5_last_out);

        /* Update the rc4 crypto key, which is seq+challenge */
        md5input[0] = in->seq;
        memcpy(&md5input[1], &raw_out.data[MSG_HDR_LEN + MD5_HASH_LEN], CHALLENGE_LEN);

        md5_init(&md5);
        md5_update(&md5, CHALLENGE_LEN + 1, md5input);
        md5_digest(&md5, MD5_HASH_LEN, ctx->rc4key);

 DEBUG(0, "The expected md5sum for the next entry is %02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x", 
              ctx->md5_last_out[0], ctx->md5_last_out[1], ctx->md5_last_out[2], ctx->md5_last_out[3],
              ctx->md5_last_out[4], ctx->md5_last_out[5], ctx->md5_last_out[6], ctx->md5_last_out[9],
              ctx->md5_last_out[8], ctx->md5_last_out[9], ctx->md5_last_out[10], ctx->md5_last_out[11],
              ctx->md5_last_out[12], ctx->md5_last_out[13], ctx->md5_last_out[14], ctx->md5_last_out[15]);

        write(ctx->clientfd, raw_out.data, raw_out.length);
        talloc_free(out);
        return ST_OK;
}

STATUS handle_chiron_msg_account(struct chiron_context *ctx, struct chiron_message *msg) {

        ctx->account_code = talloc_memdup(msg, msg->msg.account.account_code, msg->msg.account.length);
        NO_MEM_RETURN(ctx->account_code);

        send_chiron_msg_challenge(ctx, msg);
        return ST_OK;   
}

STATUS handle_connection(struct chiron_context *ctx) {
        int n;
        struct chiron_message *msg;
        enum ndr_err_code ndr_err;
        char buf[1024]; /* Purposefully static length */
        DATA_BLOB data;
        STATUS status;
 DEBUG(0, "The expected md5sum for the next entry is %02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x", 
              ctx->md5_last_out[0], ctx->md5_last_out[1], ctx->md5_last_out[2], ctx->md5_last_out[3],
              ctx->md5_last_out[4], ctx->md5_last_out[5], ctx->md5_last_out[6], ctx->md5_last_out[9],
              ctx->md5_last_out[8], ctx->md5_last_out[9], ctx->md5_last_out[10], ctx->md5_last_out[11],
              ctx->md5_last_out[12], ctx->md5_last_out[13], ctx->md5_last_out[14], ctx->md5_last_out[15]);

        write(ctx->clientfd, raw_out.data, raw_out.length);
        talloc_free(out);
        return ST_OK;
}

STATUS handle_chiron_msg_account(struct chiron_context *ctx, struct chiron_message *msg) {

        ctx->account_code = talloc_memdup(msg, msg->msg.account.account_code, msg->msg.account.length);
        NO_MEM_RETURN(ctx->account_code);

        send_chiron_msg_challenge(ctx, msg);
        return ST_OK;   
}

STATUS handle_connection(struct chiron_context *ctx) {
        int n;
        struct chiron_message *msg;
        enum ndr_err_code ndr_err;
        char buf[1024]; /* Purposefully static length */
        DATA_BLOB data;
        STATUS status;
  while ((n = read(ctx->clientfd, buf, sizeof(buf)))) {
                if (n < 0) {
                        DEBUG( 0, "Error when storing packet in buffer!");
                        return ST_PARSE_ERROR;
                } else if (n == sizeof(buf)) {
                        DEBUG(0, "Maximum packet size exceeded!");
                        return ST_PARSE_ERROR;
                }

                msg = talloc(ctx, struct chiron_message);
                NO_MEM_RETURN(msg);

                /* Copy packet to data blob */
                data.length = n;
                data.data = talloc_memdup(msg, buf, n);
                NO_MEM_RETURN(data.data);

                /* Parse the packet */
                ndr_err = ndr_pull_struct_blob_all(&data, msg, msg, (ndr_pull_flags_fn_t)ndr_pull_chiron_message);

                if (ndr_err != NDR_ERR_SUCCESS) {
                        DEBUG(0, "Could not parse this message");
                        return ST_PARSE_ERROR;
                }
                DEBUG(0, "%s", ndr_print_struct_string(msg,(ndr_print_fn_t)ndr_print_chiron_message, "chiron message", msg));

                switch (msg->msg_type) {
                        case CHIRON_ACCOUNT:
                                status = handle_chiron_msg_account(ctx, msg);
                                break;
                        case CHIRON_RESPONSE:
                                status = handle_chiron_msg_response(ctx, msg);
                                break;
                        default:
                                DEBUG(0, "Got unexpected message type: %s.", 
                                      ndr_print_chiron_msg_type_enum(msg, msg->msg_type));
                                break;
                }
 if (status != ST_OK) {
                        return status;
                }

                talloc_free(msg);
        }
        return ST_OK;
}

static STATUS daemonize(char *pid_file) {
        FILE *pidfile;
        pid_t pid;

        fclose(stdin);
        fclose(stdout);
        fclose(stderr);
        if ((pid = fork())) {
                /* Write PID file */
                pidfile = fopen(pid_file, "w");
                if (pidfile < 0)
                        exit(1);

                fprintf(pidfile, "%d\n", pid);
                fclose(pidfile);
                exit(0);
        }
        return ST_OK;
}
static STATUS listen_server(TALLOC_CTX *mem_ctx, const char *bindaddr, const char *bindport, const char *protocol, STATUS (*dispatcher)(struct chiron_context *)) {
        int sock;
        socklen_t clientlen;
        struct addrinfo hints, *server, *first_server;

        memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));
        hints.ai_flags    = AI_PASSIVE;

        getaddrinfo(bindaddr, bindport, &hints, &server);

        first_server = server;
        while (server) {
                sock = socket(server->ai_family, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
                if (sock >= 0) {
                        int optval = 1;
                        setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &optval, sizeof(optval));
                        if (bind(sock, server->ai_addr, server->ai_addrlen) < 0) {
                                close(sock);
                                sock = -1;
                        } else {

{
                                break;
                        }
                }
                server = server->ai_next;
        }

        if (sock < 0) {
                DEBUG(0, "Could not create socket in server");
                return ST_SOCKET_FAILURE;
        }
        listen(sock, 128);
        freeaddrinfo(first_server);

        DEBUG(0, "Started %s and waiting for Chiron messages on port %s", 
                 get_process_name(), CHIRON_PORT);

        /*
         * Wait for connections
         */

        clientlen = sizeof(struct addrinfo);
        while (1) {
                int clientfd;
                struct sockaddr_storage clientaddr;
                char clienthost[NI_MAXHOST];
                char clientservice[NI_MAXSERV];

                clientfd = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&clientaddr, &clientlen);
                getnameinfo((struct sockaddr *)&clientaddr, clientlen,
                            clienthost, sizeof(clienthost),
                            clientservice, sizeof(clientservice),
                            NI_NUMERICHOST | NI_NUMERICSERV);
                DEBUG(3, "Received connection from %s:%s", clienthost, clientservice);
//if (fork()) {
                //      continue;
                //} else {
                {
                        struct chiron_context *client_ctx = talloc_zero(mem_ctx, struct chiron_context);
                        NO_MEM_RETURN(client_ctx);
                        client_ctx->clientaddr = (struct sockaddr *)&clientaddr;
                        client_ctx->clientfd = clientfd;

                        dispatcher(client_ctx);

                        shutdown(client_ctx->clientfd, SHUT_RDWR);
                        close(client_ctx->clientfd);

                        talloc_free(client_ctx);
                        exit(0);
                }

        }
        shutdown(sock, SHUT_RDWR);
        close(sock);
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
        TALLOC_CTX *mem_ctx;
        STATUS rv;
        const configuration *conf;

        set_process_name(argv[0]);

        /* Initialize a memory context */
        mem_ctx = talloc_init("chirond");
  /* Read the configuration file */
        rv = read_configuration_file(mem_ctx);
        if (rv != ST_OK)
                return rv;

        conf = get_conf();

        /* Daemonize if we're not supposed to run in foreground mode */
        if (!conf->foreground) {
                daemonize(conf->pid_file);
        }

        /*
         * Open up a TCP socket the Chiron port
         */
        listen_server(mem_ctx, "::", CHIRON_PORT, "tcp", handle_connection);

        return 0;
}
```

getting error on make, ISO c does not permit named variadic macros on ubutnu

```
In file included from ../includes.h:43:0,
                 from ../chirond.c:18:
../status.h:19:26: error: ISO C does not permit named variadic macros [-Werror=variadic-macros]
```

Comment: Did you pick those flags for the compiler? Is the compiler version you are using suitable/compatible/recommended by/with the sources you are compiling?

Comment: i don't know about this, how to check it? can you tell me briefly?

Comment: Post `status.h` and `chirond.c` if possible.

Comment: how to do it? please tell me briefly? you need code?

Comment: @LPs you need chirond.c?

Comment: Add your code. Edit your question and add it.

Comment: @LPs: I don't think it's OP's code - it's available here: https://github.com/bitlair/siahsd/blob/master/status.h
I have a feeling the compiler isn't coping with variable arg macros - perhaps too old?

Comment: @MatsPetersson I got it, thx. `#define DEBUG(level, args...) debug(level, __location__, __FUNCTION__, args)` must be compiled with GCC only, because of this is a [GCC extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.2.1/gcc/Variadic-Macros.html).

Comment: so what's solution, please tell me or you need code?

Comment: I'm guessing the compiler you are using is older than the version suggested... What version of gcc are you using?

Comment: gcc version 4.7.2 (Debian 4.7.2-5)   @MatsPetersson

Comment: Or too new, if it is newer than 4 years old, perhaps?

Comment: which version you suggest?

Comment: @MatsPetersson please tell me how to solve this?

Comment: I would just change the -std=c99 to -std=gnu99 (or -std=c11). Or find a more recent version of the code, that has appropriate options for a compiler that is in use today (I personally would suggest 4.9 or later of gcc, or clang 3.6 or later - only because I'm using those - however, the error won't be fixed by using a newer compiler, I'm reasonably sure). Note that I'm just guessing based on looking at the error and the command line.

Comment: where have to change -std=c99 to -std=gnu99

Comment: I don't quite know - somewhere in the `waf` directory, I guess - like I said, I'm not familiar with either the package or the build system it uses, just analyzing what is written in your post, along with looking at the line in the source, knowing what the compiler can do, etc.

Comment: Into file `wscrpt` at `line 94`

Comment: @LPs please look at code i added, i f any issue please tell me.

Comment: Try to do what @MatsPetersson wrote.

Comment: @LPs changing -std not working?

Comment: I don't know. I'm not able to compile that project on my Debian.

Comment: Looking on the web, it seems that you could solve using gcc 4.3. Give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Have to upgrade GCC to 4.9 and if you are to lower version using follow instructions on this page.

[https://solarianprogrammer.com/2015/01/13/raspberry-pi-raspbian-install-gcc-compile-cpp-14-programs/][1]

put this lines to avoid warnings

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wvariadic-macros"

        // Your code and/or include files
        // (No variadic warnings here)
 #pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

if you have so much warnings remove -werror from CFLAGS. you can able to build.